# how to select on same table twice In one query or round-trip?

Tags: mysql, c#-4.0

Ok here is a code-snipet of what I have tried:

```
    private static void CheckForChanges(MySqlConnection connection)
    {
        DateTime hair = DateTime.Parse(SmartStyleDataset.Tables["Hair"].Compute("MAX(lastUpdated)", null).ToString());
        DateTime cloths = DateTime.Parse(SmartStyleDataset.Tables["Cloths"].Compute("MAX(lastUpdated)", null).ToString());
        DateTime accessories = DateTime.Parse(SmartStyleDataset.Tables["Accessories"].Compute("MAX(lastUpdated)", null).ToString());
        DateTime cosmetics = DateTime.Parse(SmartStyleDataset.Tables["Cosmetics"].Compute("MAX(lastUpdated)", null).ToString());

        List<String>[] NewRows = { new List<String>(), new List<String>(), new List<String>(), new List<String>() };   

        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.CommandText = 
                 "SELECT * "
                + "FROM smartstyle.table_changes_logger "
                + "WHERE  Updated > @accessories AND Table = 'accessories' ; "
                + "SELECT * "
                + "FROM smartstyle.table_changes_logger "
                + "WHERE  Updated > @cosmetics AND Table = 'cosmetics' ; "
                + "SELECT * "
                + "FROM smartstyle.table_changes_logger "
                + "WHERE  Updated > @cloths AND Table = 'cloths' ; "
                + "SELECT * "
                + "FROM smartstyle.table_changes_logger "
                + "WHERE  Updated > @hair AND Table = 'hair'";

            command.Parameters.Add("@cloths", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.Timestamp).Value = cloths.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            command.Parameters.Add("@hair", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.Timestamp).Value = hair.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            command.Parameters.Add("@accessories", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.Timestamp).Value = accessories.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            command.Parameters.Add("@cosmetics", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.Timestamp).Value = cosmetics.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                do
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        NewRows[0].Add(reader.GetString(1));
                        NewRows[1].Add(reader.GetString(2));
                        NewRows[2].Add(reader.GetString(3));
                        NewRows[3].Add(reader.GetString(4));
                    }

                } while (reader.NextResult());

            }
        }
 }
```

but this doesn't work I get the following generic error from mysql I dont understand
**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Table = 'accessories' ; SELECT * FROM smartstyle.table_changes_logger WHERE  Upd' at line 1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape [reserved words in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) like `table` with backticks.

```
SELECT * 
FROM smartstyle.table_changes_logger 
WHERE  Updated > @accessories 
AND `Table` = 'accessories'
```